# how to get this result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dropdown on page when user selects any value from it ; i am passing that value and filtering the result.
suppose if user select any bike from dropdown then from user table only those record should come which have that 
bike and also those records should come where user have not any bike .

```
   username               vehicleID 
   =========              =======
   john                   1
   peter                  1
   maria                  2
   raso                 
   pritam                 4
```

if user selects vehicleID 2 then raso should also come along with maria.
I do not want to use UNION for this .

IF user does not select any thing all data should come by default on page

any other idea. thanks in advance

Comment: I can't understand why you would need union if you can just say SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE VEHICLEID=2 OR VEHICLEID IS NULL. It's the most basic thing in that SQL must do.

Comment: depending on table size and indexing, a `union` may run faster because you can eliminate the `OR`

Comment: So your design supports a user only having 0 or 1 vehicle?  Or is there a user table, a userVehicle table, and a Vehicle table?  If multiple vehicles then left join becomes of reasonable use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following query, where the `@VehicleID` is the `SelectedValue` of the `dropdownlist`.

```
SELECT Username
FROM Table
WHERE @VehicleID IS NULL
OR VehicleID=@VehicleID
OR VehicleID IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 : This actually does everything the OP asked for.  Records with NULL vehicleID always come through, not suppling a value the the @parameter causes the whole table to be returned.